# Firebase deploy function Build failed: Build error details not available

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-build

I have several projects having the same issue. It was deploying fine just a day ago. Now the deployment will quit with an error:

Build failed: Build error details not available.

The logs from the GCP is shown below (replaced with project-name):

```
{
  "textPayload": "Step #5 - \"exporter\": \u001b[31;1mERROR: \u001b[0mfailed to export: failed to write image to the following tags: [us.gcr.io/project-name/gcf/us-central1/e2c2be8f-3c6d-4689-b474-21e8817b750e:ssr_version-162: GET https://storage.googleapis.com/us.artifacts.project-name.appspot.com/containers/images/sha256:b4c8acdb6f61130b2c632d1378bc84c602d6f4af2286fb9fb174e8f8376ec19f?access_token=REDACTED: unsupported status code 404; body: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Error><Code>NoSuchKey</Code><Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message><Details>No such object: us.artifacts.project-name.appspot.com/containers/images/sha256:b4c8acdb6f61130b2c632d1378bc84c602d6f4af2286fb9fb174e8f8376ec19f</Details></Error>]",
  "insertId": "1263383d-eff6-4302-bb99-8a8a2ad01867-554",
  "resource": {
    "type": "build",
    "labels": {
      "build_trigger_id": "",
      "build_id": "1263383d-eff6-4302-bb99-8a8a2ad01867",
      "project_id": "project-name"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2020-10-23T06:11:27.265803715Z",
  "severity": "INFO",
  "labels": {
    "build_step": "Step #5 - \"exporter\""
  },
  "logName": "projects/project-name/logs/cloudbuild",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2020-10-23T06:11:27.777967721Z"
}
```

It seems like the build fail when they couldn't find/access the cached copy of the image in us.artifacts bucket.

Have been trying to reach out to Google but there was no response so far. Anyone else having this issue? Not seen any reports by others so far.

Comment: I'm also having the same issue it started on the 4/10/20, Haven't had any luck so far

Comment: I can deploy each function individually with firebase deploy --only functions:name but it fails when deploying all functions at the same time :/

Comment: Seeing the same issue. Do you have any deletion Lifecycle rules active on your artifacts cloud storage bucket?

Answer (score 7):

### Updated answer

Deleting the entire bucket from Google cloud storage (us.artifacts.{{project}}.appspot.com) not just its contents works for me.

### Original answer (above is better)

1. From google cloud functions interface I deleted all the functions
2. Redeployed each function individually `firebase deploy --only functions:$name`

I was then able to redeploy all functions via cloud build + locally via the firebase command

Comment: I am getting the same issue. Wouldn't deleting the functions from Google Cloud Functions interface break my app though?

Comment: this solved my issue in 2021. not sure why deleting the contents didn't work - I had to delete the entire bucket

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. In my case, I made sure the run-time version of Node on GCP matched the one in my local development environment. So I had to downgrade my node v15 to node v12 which is what was running on GCP for my project.